# Run a jQuery live search on every keyup

Tags: jquery

Site: http://holyhearttheatre.com/

Has a live search feature right above the list events (scroll down a little).

Problem: If you spell the event wrong, you need to clear the text field for the search field to resume. Just try searching for a Show, and then misspell it. You need to erase the whole input field to start searching again.

How can I make it so that if someone spells the word wrong, it will search as soon as it has a match on what's in the search field?

Example:   There's an event called "Happy Tree". Searching for the word "tree" works, but if I search for "treee" it will return no results, and I'll need to clear the search field to get results.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
var liveSearch = function(){
var $events = $('.events');
var $searchTerm = $('.search');

$($searchTerm).keyup(function () {
    var filter = $($searchTerm).val();
    if ( filter ) {
        var $found = $('.event-title:contains("' + filter + '")').closest('.events');
        $events.not($found).hide()
    } else {
        $events.show();
    }
})
```

}

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.live-search').on('keyup', function(){
        liveSearch();
    });
});
```

It seems like on.keyup would be what I'm looking for?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hide the events that don't match with `$events.not($found).hide()`, but forget to (re)show the ones that do match (in case any are hidden). Something like:

```
$found.show();
$events.not($found).hide()
```